# Odoo external id difference in Metadata and in FormView

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

What is usage and difference between xml_id in Metadata and in FormView ? 
For example in Customer form, menu Edit FormView, External (XML) ID is `base.view_partner_form` and the model is `ir.ui.view`. But in View Metadata of the same form, the XML ID is `base.res_partner_2` and the model is res.partner.

I try to search these two `xml_id` in database table `ir_model_data` and sure both are there.

Please help, how each of them are used ?

Answer (score 1):

The XML ID **base.res_partner_2** you saw in Metadata is belonged to demo data of odoo and the XML ID **base.view_partner_form** id form view ID of **res.partner** model.
These all xml ids are stored in the same table of odoo as you mentioned table **ir_model_data**.

Check the xml files of odoo you'll get both the ids are there in code .. Fact is you'll find 1 id in demo data files and another one in form view as the id of view.

**For example:**

odoo-11/addons/account/demo/account_demo.xml

odoo-11/odoo/addons/base/res/res_partner_view.xml

Comment: Thanks for your answer